# Set numberOfRowsInSection for tableview as per the Array of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a quick question here...

**Here I have an Array named arrayDishDetails**

```
{
    "dishid": "5",
    "cusineid": "1",
    "dishname": "Cheese Fries",
    "dishimage": "noimage.png",
    "type": "NA",
    "description": "VEG FRIES",
    "price": "120",
    "swiggy_status": "enable",
    "preflag": "true",
    "pre": [
        {
            "preid": "112",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "BATTER FRIED FISH",
            "preprice": "70",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "109",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "JALAPENO POPPERS",
            "preprice": "50",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "110",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "CHICKEN SAUSAGES",
            "preprice": "50",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "111",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "CHICKEN NUGGETS",
            "preprice": "50",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "113",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "SHREDDED CHICKEN",
            "preprice": "50",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "114",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "CHICKEN POPCORN",
            "preprice": "50",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "105",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "GRATED CHEESE",
            "preprice": "30",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "272",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Chili",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "273",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Jalapeno Cheese",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "274",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Salsa",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "275",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "BBQ",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "276",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Mayo",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "277",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Schezwan",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "278",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Pizza Sauce",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "279",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Chipotle",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "280",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Tandoori",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "281",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Garlic Mayo",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "282",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Tartare sauce",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "283",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Thai Sweet Chili",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "284",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Makhani Gravy",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "6"
        },
        {
            "preid": "106",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "CRUSHED TORTILLAS",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "107",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "BEANS",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "115",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "FRIED MAGGI",
            "preprice": "20",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "270",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": "Chat Masala",
            "preprice": "10",
            "cat_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "preid": "108",
            "pretype": "Multi",
            "prenm": " MAGIC MASALA",
            "preprice": "10",
            "cat_id": "3"
        }
    ],
    "modifier_cat": [
        {
            "cat_id": "3",
            "cat_name": "ADD ONS",
            "modifier_selection": "1"
        },
        {
            "cat_id": "6",
            "cat_name": "Extra Sauces",
            "modifier_selection": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now in my tableview, I set **titleForHeaderInSection** like this.

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self.arrayDishDetails valueForKey:@"modifier_cat"] valueForKey:@"cat_name"] objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

I set **numberOfSectionsInTableView** like this..

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.arrayDishDetails valueForKey:@"modifier_cat"] count];
}
```

Now, My question is, How can I filter the **"pre"** Array to get **"prenm"** by **"cat_id"** from **"modifier_cat"** Array so that I can get the 2 different Categories?

**For Example :-**

for **"cat_id" = "3"** I want all the **"prenm"** like "prenm": "BATTER FRIED FISH","JALAPENO POPPERS", "CHICKEN SAUSAGES", etc from **"pre"** Array.

And same for **"cat_id" = "6"**

I have looked for many solutions to the filter Array but can't get help for mine.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

I got some hint from the answer of @Karthik and I set my numberofrows for my tableview like this:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cat_id = %@", [[[self.arrayDishDetails valueForKey:@"modifier_cat"]valueForKey:@"cat_id"]objectAtIndex:section]]; 
NSArray *filteredArray = [[self.arrayDishDetails valueForKey:@"pre"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
 
return filteredArray.count; 
}
```

Now, how can I set the **"prenm"** for each section (here 2 sections 0 and 1) as per **"cat_id"** of **"modifier_cat"** Array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking on to filtering array with custom objects. I am assuming the JSON you have put are mapped to custom objects. Add the below code to filter pre array with cat_id from modifier_cat array.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self getFilteredArray: section].count;
}
```

And to display the cell with items please use the below method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: @"FishDetailsCell"];
    UILabel *fishStyle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];
    Pre *pre = [[self getFilteredArray:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    fishStyle.text = pre.prenm;
    fishStyle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [cell addSubview: fishStyle];
    return cell;
}
```

// Method to reuse for filtering array

```
- (NSArray *)getFilteredArray:(NSInteger)section {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"cat_id = %@", [[[self.arrayDishDetails valueForKey:@"modifier_cat"]valueForKey:@"cat_id"]objectAtIndex: section]];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [[self.arrayDishDetails valueForKey: @"pre"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
    return filteredArray;
}
```

Hope this one helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me. And I got numberofrows for my tableview like this: 

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cat_id = %@", [[[self.arrayDishDetails valueForKey:@"modifier_cat"]valueForKey:@"cat_id"]objectAtIndex:section]];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [[self.arrayDishDetails valueForKey:@"pre"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    
    return filteredArray.count;
}

Comment: But How will I be able to print "prenm" for each section in my tableview?

Comment: Do you want prenm as section title or row title?

Comment: each prenm as rows for each section. Like for section 0, all prenm will be of cat_id = 3, and for section 1, all prenm will be of cat_id = 6.

Comment: So for each row you want the title as prenm like

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, can you please accept and upvote my answer. It will be helpful to increase my SO rating.@iHarshil

Answer (score 0):

So you can do that the below way:

```
for cat in [self.arrayDishDetails valueForKey:@"modifier_cat"] {
    NSString *cat_id = [cat valueForKey:@"cat_id"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cat_id = %@", cat_id];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [pre filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    //Here you will be getting your filtered array for cat_id 3 and 6 one after another, store it as per your requirement.
    NSArray *filteredprenmArrayForCatId = [filteredArray valueForKey:@"prenm"];    
}
```

Hope this helps.